# Convert from one json format to another

Tags: php, json, string

I have a JSON formatted string that i get from an API call. however the format of the JSON string that i get from the API call is something similar to this.

```
{"offset":1,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123"}}
```

I want it to be in the following format

```
{"offset":1,"result":[{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123"}]}
```

**Note:** kindly look at the addition square braces in the folded JSON.

How can i achieve this in PHP . Im fairly new to PHP a little help here is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: where are your codes that generate the JSON string

Comment: @Ghost : He got it from API

Comment: I dont't know if you can do that, but if there is an array that means you may have many results one day. If you do that have you think about this case ?

Comment: basically, just decode, add dimension to that depth, reencode

Comment: Hopefully your real json doesn't have that spurious trailing `"` after `123`

Comment: @MarkBaker yes sry it doesnt have the "...typo

Comment: @Ghost i tried adding dimensions by decoding and reencoding using for each.. Dint help me much.

Comment: How are you using foreach? Please show more code where you have the actual problem.

Comment: @KariSöderholm i enclosed the entire JSON that i got from the API with in [ ] so that i can decode the json later. Because i get multiple JSON responses from the API that are comma seperated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using PHP's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) functions. Something like:

```
$jsonFromApi = '{"offset":1,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123}}';
$array = json_decode($jsonFromApi, true);
$array['result'] = array($array['result']);
$newJson = json_encode($array);
```

**Edit:** Here is an example of using foreach for doing this to a series of comma separated json strings.

```
$originalData = '{"offset":1,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123}},{"offset":2,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123}},{"offset":3,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123}}';

// Convert original data to valid JSON by wrapping it in brackets []. Makes it a JSON array.
$json = '['.$originalData.']';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$convertedJsonStrings = array();
foreach ($array as $data) {
    $data['result'] = array($data['result']);
    $convertedJsonStrings[] = json_encode($data);
}
echo implode(',', $convertedJsonStrings);
```

Here we can't directly use `json_decode()` for `$originalData` since it is not valid JSON as it is.

Comment: This works ..but what if i have similar JSON strings that are comma seperated . for eg: {"offset":1,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123}},{"offset":2,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":333}}

Comment: If you have several similar JSON strings in the same format that are just comma separated you could just do `$jsonStrings = explode(',', $originalData);` and then loop through the `$jsonStrings` variable using foreach and run the above code for each string. And in the end if needed use `implode()` to put the converted strings back together separated by comma if you want.

Comment: I will edit my post to show an example of using foreach in this case.

Comment: The edited code doesnt work cause while using explode at comma the entire json keys are considered as separate arrays and hence the output is null.

Comment: Good point! I didn't think about that. Just a moment I will try to edit to make it work.

Comment: The second example has been updated on my post. The code should work now.

Comment: ya works ...thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert original into JSON object, take out `result`.

```
var originalJSONObj = JSON.parse(original);
var result = originalJSONObj.result;
```

Create another object with `modifiedJSONObj.offset = 1` and `modifiedJSONObj.result = []` and finally  `modifiedJSONObj.result.push(result)`.

Comment: Your answer looks like JavaScript. The question is about doing this in PHP.

Comment: yea i want to do it in PHP... but thanks for ur reply :)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I don't know PHP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, something like:

```
$json = '{"offset":1,"result":{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":123}}';
$data = json_decode($json);
$data->result = [$data->result];
$json = json_encode($data);
var_dump($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// i fixed the json that you are able to receive from the api
// maybe you could check it also
$data = '{
    "offset": 1,
    "result": {
        "host": "x.x.x.x",
        "count": "123"
    }
}';

// decode the json from api
$data = json_decode($data, true);

// create new data from decoded data
$new_data = array(
    'ofsset' => $data['offset'],
    'result' => array(
        $data['result']
    )
);

// encode it again 
echo json_encode($new_data);
```